# How to replace backslash and single quote pattern in bash?

Tags: string, bash, unix, sed

I would like to replace the following pattern `\\\\'` with `\'`

So a text like:

```
ABC DEF \\\'S XYZ
```

Would become:

```
ABC DEF \'S XYZ
```

I have tried using `sed` as such:

```
sed "s/\\\\\\\\\'/\\\\\'/g"
```

But it's not replacing anything. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different approaches depending on using single or double quotes:

```
$ cat a
hello \\\\' aaa
afa
```

Single quotes - need to close and open again to insert the single quote:

```
$ sed 's#\\\\\\\\'"'"'#X'"'"'#g' a
hello X' aaa
afa
```

Double quotes - every `\` needs to be escaped three times:

```
$ sed "s#\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'#\\\'#g" a
hello \' aaa
afa
```

Good reading: [Remove backslashes from a text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169210/40596)

> 1. **In a shell** (like `bash`) you can escape backslash by backslash. So instead of `\` write `\\`. Enclosing the string between double
>      quotes `"` makes backslash behaviour more
>      complicated[<sup><1></sup>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03) but double backslash will still produce
>      a single backslash. Enclosing the string between single quotes `'`
>      makes every character to be treated literally except `'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "ABC DEF \\\'S XYZ" | sed -r 's/\\+/\\/g'
```

Output: `ABC DEF \'S XYZ`

Here `-r` switch of `sed` is for Extended regular expressions. `sed` will match one or more occurrences of `\` (`\\+`) throughout the line and replace the matches with `\` (`\\`).

Answer (score 0):

This one works :

```
echo ABC DEF \\\'S XYZ | sed -r 's/(.*)\\\\\\(.*)/\1 \\\2/g'
```